# How can I detect if a file has Unix line feeds (\n) or Windows line feeds (\r\n)?

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, newline

I am altering a file by means of a FileStream (it is a very large file and I just need to alter the header without rewriting the whole thing.

The file can have either Unix or Windows line feeds, and it is important for me to know which so that I can write the correct line feed characters back into the file when I update it.

I could write a simple function to use a FileStream to read the file in blocks and check for the line feed characters.

But this problem must have been solved before, if not in C# then in the Win32 API?

What's the most efficient way to detect the line feed style of the file?

Comment: Not sure, hence the comment, but would it be possible to use a regular expression such as: `\r\n$`? This would check that the line feed ends with a `\r\n`. If it does not, then, it must be a Unix line.

Comment: Not really possible, as using any of the "ReadLine" methods on the .Net framework file access objects strips the newline characters. They are good if you don't care what newline style a file is using. If I read the file as a stream, I could do something like you suggest (which basically amounts to the method I may resort to..)

Comment: Can you guarantee that all line endings are consistent within a file? Technically it would be possible to have differently mixed line endings within the same file.

Comment: If you would just be reading the data I had suggested to use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` method. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) as it can handle all variants of line endings. But this does not solve the problem to write the same endings back int the file. :-(

Comment: I'm happy enough to just read the first one or two lines to determine the linefeed character. I am replacing the header on a file in place, so as long as I get the first one correct, I will not corrupt the file...

Comment: Well, then you might also want to have a look at this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015611/determine-what-line-ending-is-used-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions. I was surprised not to find something easily reusable, so I created a simple function that I include here. Note that it just finds the first newline character (\n or \r\n) and returns that as the match. Enough for my needs, but perhaps not robust.

```
    public bool TryDetectNewLine(string path, out string newLine)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            char prevChar = '\0';

            // Read the first 4000 characters to try and find a newline
            for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
            {
                int b;
                if ((b = fileStream.ReadByte()) == -1) break;

                char curChar = (char)b;

                if (curChar == '\n')
                {
                    newLine = prevChar == '\r' ? "\r\n" : "\n";
                    return true;
                }

                prevChar = curChar;
            }

            // Returning false means could not determine linefeed convention
            newLine = Environment.NewLine;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As Per stated there is really no way to detrmine the contents of a text file without openign it up and streaming through the bytes. You might get lucking if your using http to download the file, you could get a mime type that idicates the type of file, but most often its just "octet-stream".

While you can brute force it, and read till you find a line feed ("\n") then back up one character and see if there is carriage return  ("\r"), I would take a more staistical approach since you have to read the data any way.

1) Pick a sample size of bytes to read in that should get you al least 2 or 3 records from the file.

2) Store each byte encounter (i'massumign single byte char set here) as a histogram. You can do this by storing your count in an arry indexed by the byte value or you could use a dictionary.

3) Take a look at the carriage return and line feed values counts. If you have a line feed count and no carriage returns, then it is a unix file. If carraige return and line feed counts then it is a windows file.

What this approach also would allow you to do is to a quality check on the inbound file. Do you have charcaters in you histogram that are not aplha numeric ? Then someone has passed you a binary file. Expecting all upper case ? Then look for counts outside the upercase characters. There are a number of checks you could do to keep from processing a non text file.

Comment: Both your and @Per's solution assume that all line endings are consistent per file. In the wild, it could technically be very well possible to have mixed line ending markers.

Comment: True, but the excercise here is to detrmine if a file is unix or windows. I am assuming that the inbound files are in one format or the other because of what is stated in the question. If one expected mixed LF & CR/LF terminated records, then it would probably not matter which the header row was terminated with.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to be 100% certain if it is a Unix or DOS file since most editors don't correct a file with 'wrong' endings when opened/saved.

I would read the file as a stream and search for occurrences of "\r\n" and only '\n'

Using a simple statistical analysis (i.e. which one has the highest hit count) on the result of the search will likely give you the correct answer. If the file is huge, then reading the first X% of the file will be sufficient.

A simpler solution is of course to only search for "\r\n" and if found, assume it is a DOS file. This should work to 100% if the file is machine-generated.

As for any existing code in the .NET Framework/WinAPI, I have yet to see any that performs this operation.