# MySqlBulkLoader for Mac / Windows Files

Tags: c#, mysql, newline, bulk-load

I use MySqlBulkLoader to load files into the table. The issue I have is that this file could come from both Mac and Windows which means the LineTerminator could be \r\n or just \n. Is there a way to load both these with the same code .. meaning can we specify multiple LineTerminators for the same MySqlBulkLoader or is there a way to change the LineTerminators in the file if it is Mac to CR-LF and then do a bulk load ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. You can try to find the Line Terminator using the method in

[How can I detect if a file has Unix line feeds (\n) or Windows line feeds (\r\n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829559/how-can-i-detect-if-a-file-has-unix-line-feeds-n-or-windows-line-feeds-r-n)

and set the line terminator on the mysqlbulkloader accordingly.